# HTML textbox is resetting itself after 5 characters. What may be causing this?

Tags: jquery, html, razor

Using an MVC Razor table for users to input various pieces of info. One column has text inputs. I want to add comma's to every third character while they're typing. I'm using a library called accounting.js. I use this same library and its functions throughout with no issue.

As I'm typing in these specific text boxes I'm limited to five characters (including the comma). Upon the 6th character it resets to empty. I'm not doing the resetting purposely. There's other strange behavior when I fool with how the input is received, but truthfully I'm not sure if that matters much.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Jquery code that see's the td I'm typing in and spits back out the formatted number:

```
$('#bapdSublineValSubmitTBL').on('input', 'td:nth-child(7)', function () {
   var td = $(this);
   var limit = +td.find('input').val();
   td.parent().find('.bapdLimits').val(accounting.formatNumber(limit, 0, ','));
});
```

HTML Razor:

```
<td class="pdLimit" style="width:10%;">
   @* 6 *@
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center pr-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control subLineInputs bapdLimits" id="baPdLimit" placeholder="Type Limits" />
   </div>
</td>
```

There's nothing directly glaring to me that says why it's happening. If there are alternatives to adding comma's to a respective Razor page (table) I'm certainly all ears. I've not been successful.

Screenshot .. As I'm typing the 6th character sends it back to empty.

P.S. I was typing in that 2nd text box. The cursor is where it should be. To clarify typing in one text box doesn't change another to 0. Just itself. Thanks again for the help. Always appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints and debugged this? I would imagine something is not working correctly when you call `accounting.formatNumber(limit, 0, ',')` on the sixth digit..

Comment: @RyanWilson I did, but I'm not able to decipher where exactly the error is happening. I'm certain it's something conflicting with accounting library. I found an alternative to using this. So i'm just going to post that as it did solve my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you got to the sixth digit, I would have set the break point on the line with the call to `accounting`, then pasted the `accounting` call in your `console` window and with a  log to see what it was doing.